# How to not allow scrapy to retry timed out websites?

Tags: python, scrapy

For optimization purposes, I need to my spider to skip website that has been once timed out, and dont let scrapy que it and try it again and again.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I just found out,
in setting set :
"RETRY_ENABLED = False" that will take care of it :)